# HTML Hyperlinks and HTML Structure

Tags: html, excel, hyperlink

I'm a mech engineer w/ no experience in HTML, doing an odd task for my boss.

I have managed to save the excel sheet (contains hyperlinks) to HTML format. However, I'd like to edit these hyperlinks within the HTML code.

I right-clicked on the test.htm document and viewed the HTML in notepad. I expected to be able to find the hyperlink at this stage.

My question is:

What is the structure of HTML files, in the sense that the hyperlink must be stored *somewhere*, how do I view it, preferably within notepad?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with the way excel saves to html. It generates a **filename.htm** which acts as a viewer, and then places data for each sheet inside a "filename_files" folder. Inside, you'll find **sheetxxx.htm** files (which actually contain the href you are looking for). When you open **filename.htm**, scripts inside it load the corresponding sheets into the page.

And this is why you won't find what you want inside the main file. Keep in mind that html is dynamic, which means that, differently from opening a static file in notepad, it can be configured to perform actions, changing what you see in the page and its code behind (Dom Explorer)

Comment: Hey Rafael, thank you for your reply. It is very clear and has adjusted my understanding.

However, this part has confused me, " Keep in mind that html is dynamic, which means that, differently from opening a static file in notepad, it can be configured to perform actions, changing what you see in the page and its code behind (Dom Explorer)"

Can you link me to a webpage that explains this so I can read?

Comment: I surely can, but if this answers your question (what is happening) you should accept the answer. Here you can read about Javascript https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_intro.asp. Just focus on the fact that, when you open a html document, you're not always opening something static - with javascript/html, it's like opening a program(software) where things change, files are loaded and many other events take place.

Answer (score 0):

Hyperlinks in HTML are designated by the "a href" tag. For instance,

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">This Link Goes To Google</a>
```

creates a link that says "This Link Goes To Google"